# AdMob SDK for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, admob, ads-api

Trying to get my Universal app released and I rely on AdMob ads for revenue in this particular app.  I'm having an issue getting AdMob support working, though I keep finding references to people actually running AdMob on their iPad Simulators.

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'AdMobInvalidLibaryVersionException',
>   reason: 'This version of AdMob SDK is
>   incompatible with the iPhone 3.2 SDK
>   or above. Make sure your Active SDK is
>   set to 3.1.X . If you need to build
>   with 3.2, use the 3.2 preview
>   library.'

I have not been able to find this "3.2 preview library" anywhere.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the binaries for the preview in the current SDK under:

/extra/libAdMob32.a

/extra/libAdMob32NoThumb.a

Unfortunately, the ads still do not work on an iPad device. If you currently want to build on 3.2 and at least have your iPhone ads working, find the previous release. It does not throw the AdMobInvalidLibaryVersionException and compiles fine on 3.2 The only issue is that you won't be able to get any ads on an iPad device. (Works fine in simulator for some reason).